# rspec: 'should_receive' with multiple argument expectations

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, integration-testing

I have a function which receives a complex argument (an HTML string).  I want to check multiple conditions about this string, i.e.:

```
receiver.should_receive(:post_data).with(json_content).with(id_matching(5))
```

Multiple `with` arguments doesn't work, any alternatives?  I'm happy to define custom matchers if it's possible to make a compound one in some way.

Obviously I could run the same test multiple times and test different things about the result, however this is an integration test which takes several seconds to run, so I don't want to make it even slower.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

At time of writing, the accepted answer (use a custom matcher with custom description), appears to be the best option.  However it isn't perfect, ideally `with` would support a concept of 'this was an item of the expected type, but wasn't the one we expected', instead of a pure binary match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a custom matcher, but you can readily define your error reporting so that you can give specifics about what failed and why. See https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/Custom-Matchers .

In particular, the custom matcher would be supplied as the argument to `with`, as mentioned in the last sentence of the first paragraph of the "Argument Matchers" section of https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks.

As for error reporting, there are no custom failure methods that apply to this use case, but the `description` method of the custom matcher is used generate the string shown as the "expected" value and, though not its purpose, can be defined to output anything you want regarding the failed match.

Comment: The second link looks useful.  I've seen the first, which doesn't give much detail about complex matchers.  Tomorrow I'll have a play and see if I can come up with a sensible matcher.

Comment: +1 for being relevant, but it doesn't quite answer the question.  The behaviour of 'with' is a bit different to 'should'.  A custom matcher for should will report why it didn't match.  However 'with' appears to wait until it receives an argument which does match.  If it doesn't match, rspec just reports what the non-matching argument is.  I.e. there doesn't appear to be a way to define custom failure messages for 'with'.  I'd be happy to be proved wrong though!

Comment: I agree there's a difference. I updated the answer to reflect where the custom matcher would appear (i.e. as the argument to the standard `with` method), but that still leaves the matter of the error message.   Although it's a hack, you could modify the `description` method of the custom matcher to output any information you'd like regarding the failed match. This method is what's used following "expected: " when `with` reports it's failure. Since there isn't a `failure_message_for_with` defined in the rspec code, I suspect this may be the only "hook" you have.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it a bit more.  The description might improve the error messages, it might be good enough.

Comment: I found the rspec code that generates the error message and confirmed that there are no other hooks available.  See `raise_unexpected_message_args_error` in https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/ccf32843497cc98a9f0473bc92ad3f33b3f8e98a/lib/rspec/mocks/error_generator.rb At the risk of repeating myself, though, the `description` method of the custom matcher can output anything you want about the failed match by accessing instance variable information stored by the matcher code.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you don't even need a custom matcher and the block form is sufficient for you.

```
receiver.should_receive(:post_data) do |*args|
  json_content = args.first
  json_content.should_not be_empty
  json_content.should include "some string"
end
```

See RSpec Mocks documentation, section [Arbitrary Handling](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#arbitrary-handling)